# In store pick up is only option for orders under $50

Tags: magento2, shipping

For some reason when customers spend $50 or less, the only option displayed is in-store pick up. There are no shipping options displayed.

I can't find anything in the shipping options that would be controlling this.

Any ideas?

Comment: For Store Pickup have you use any third party extension?

Comment: Maybe all shipping options configured have a minimum cart value of $50+. Check your `shipping_tablerates` db table if you’re using the standard shipping module.